# Focus on 1 muscle group or not

Tags: weight-loss, abdominals, muscle-gain, muscle-imbalance

I am thinking of building some muscle to help burn off the excess fat on my body. Of every part of my body, my abdomen has the most fat. So, I was thinking of focusing on my abs and obliques. But I have heard that a muscle imbalance can cause pain similar to that of a pulled muscle. So should I focus on my abs and obliques or not?

Answer (score 1):

A few things you should understand:

**Muscle imbalance can indeed cause long term pain or injuries** so if you work out, you want to work on your entire body (and work on mental health is as important in my opinion but this ain't the place for that I guess).

Also, **focussing on your abs will not help on getting rid of belly fat faster**. The contrary will happen. You need to burn fat over your entire body and most ab exercises don't burn a lot of calories, so you won't lose fat fast. It's better to do compound movements and some cardio if you want to burn fat.

Hope it helps!

Comment: So, that means that for every day I do abdominal exercises, I should also exercise my chest and back, is that what you are saying? I have noticed when I had long term abdominal muscle pain(lasted a year) that doing an abdominal stretch helped with the pain and I did do basically no back exercises for 2 months(that is how long I could do just abdominal exercises before I had the 1 year long muscle pain) so maybe that pain was caused by a muscle imbalance.

Comment: Caters, yes to your first question in general.